# editing nginx.conf file over cloud foundry

Tags: django, nginx, angular6, cloud-foundry

I have an application built using django, angular and hosted using cloudfoundry. 
partial URL with http fails to proceed, for example http://www.example.com/home will fail but https://www.example.com/home will work fine.

same way http://www.example.com will redirect to https://www.example.com but when given with half URL the redirection is failing.

So i did some research on this issue, and found that nginx.conf file needs to be edited and could not find more. is it need to be uploaded with the django application to cloud foundry

any guide over this will be very helpful
Out put of CF PUSH:

```
C:\***\dcms-api>cf push -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git
Pushing from manifest to org DCMS / space Development as ***@***.com...
Using manifest file C:\***\dcms-api\manifest.yml
Getting app info...
Updating app with these attributes...
  name:                dcms
  path:                C:\***\dcms-api
  buildpacks:
    https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git
  disk quota:          512M
  health check type:   port
  instances:           1
  memory:              256M
  stack:               cflinuxfs3
  env:
    ACCEPT_EULA
    DB_HOST
    DB_NAME
    DB_PORT
    DB_USER
    DB_USER_PASSWORD
    SYS_NAME
    SYS_PASSWORD
  routes:
    dcms***.com

Updating app dcms...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 385.10 KiB / 385.10 KiB [=====================================================================] 100.00% 1s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 9c6ffac8- creating container for instance eb1fe223-
   Cell 9c6ffac8- successfully created container for instance eb1fe223-
   Downloading app package...
   Downloading build artifacts cache...
   Downloaded app package (2M)
   Downloaded build artifacts cache (108M)
   -----> Download go 1.12.4
   -----> Running go build supply
   /tmp/buildpackdownloads/adf6125a52c1a65c9523985b5a87ec38 ~
   -----> Nginx Buildpack version 1.1.9
   -----> Supplying nginx
   -----> No nginx version specified - using mainline => 1.17.10
   -----> Installing nginx 1.17.10
          Download 



 [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/nginx/nginx_1.17.10_linux_x64_cflinuxfs3_2fe87dae.tgz]
          **WARNING** nginx 1.17.x will no longer be available in new buildpacks released after 2020-05-01.
          See: https://nginx.org/
          **ERROR** nginx.conf file must be configured to respect the value of `{{port}}`
          **ERROR** Could not validate nginx.conf: no {{port}} in nginx.conf
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
   Exit status 223
   Cell 9c6ffac8- stopping instance eb1fe223-
   Cell 9c6ffac8- destroying container for instance eb1fe223-
   Cell 9c6ffac8- successfully destroyed container for instance eb1fe223-
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

and i have a doubt on where to place the following nginx.conf?

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include mime.types;
  sendfile on;
  gzip on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  keepalive_timeout 30;

  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name apps1-bg-int.icloud.intel.com .apps1-bg-int.icloud.intel.com;

    location / {
      root /home/vcap/app/static/UI;
      index index.html;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which buildpack are you using? Please also include the full output of `cf push` for your app. This will tell us more about what is deployed for your app. Generally for Python apps, you don't need/don't have Nginx.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look and see where the redirect is coming from. Check your domain registrar, sometimes they have redirect services in place. Also, check your application. Often times the application will initiate these redirects and it may be doing it incorrectly. Your app will be behind at least one layer of proxies, so it needs to look at the x-forwarded-port or x-forwarded-proto headers to make the decision. I haven't done that with Django, but I'm sure there's a way. It's a common deployment to be behind a reverse proxy and to need to deal with these headers. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
listen {{port}};
```

It works for me.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/index.html#port